# Why is my electric going on only in half my house?

Tags: electrical

I need to know how my electric would be going out only in half my home.

I have a electrical pole leaning forward toward my yard away from my house.
My electric has been going off in all my mobile home except my fridge and two outlets and my master bedroom and master bathroom - everything else is kicking off, including my heat pump.

The heat pump makes a big sound that sounds like it is begging for electricity, then my electric will go off. It kicks off a few minutes then comes back in.

We have had the transformer changed, the electric company also fixed the clips at the top of my pole. This seems to have fixed the problem for about a week, but it snowed and was cold, and now it went back off. The power stays off a few mins then kicks backs on. My husband went to wiggle the wires going into the box out on the pole and the electric comes back on.

I don't know if this is the problem where the pole is leaning crinkling the wires into my outside box up but seems like that's causing it to go off or the wire into the box on the pole is being pushed up and not straight causing it.

Comment: Couple questions for you.  What country are you in?  When your husband wiggles the wires on "the pole", what pole are you talking about?  What electrical pole is "leaning forward toward my yard"?  Pictures are *very* helpful here so feel free to post some (encourage you to do so).

Comment: Is your meter on that electric pole, as part of that "outside box"?

Comment: You need to call your power company to come back and have another look because something is _still_ not right. Don't go poking at wires outside on the pole, especially if there's snow on the ground - that's a good way to end up dead.

Answer (score 5):

Your question lacks details we need to accurately answer your question (see my comments above).  However, it sounds like you are losing one leg of your service.  In the US (are you in the US or Canada?) electricity is delivered in 110 volt increments (commonly referred to as "legs").  Each house has two of these "legs" delivered to it.  Again, each "leg" carries 110 volts.  When you need more power (e.g. for clothes dryers, water heaters, AC, etc.) these two legs are combined to provide 220 volts.  Everything else in your home will get electricity from one leg or the other.  If one of these legs fails (e.g. by a connection being broken due to a bad transformer or a damaged pole) then you will lose electricity in "half" of your home.

The heat pump probably runs on 220 volts and requires *both* legs to run properly.  You are probably hearing it strain to start on just one leg.  This is dangerous to both you and the heat pump.  You will either burn out the motor or start a fire (maybe both).

Comment: IMPORTANT:  TURN OFF YOUR HEAT PUMP UNTIL THIS PROBLEM IS RESOLVED! You could easily burn it out with this going on.  Sorry for the all caps but this is important.  If the POCO changed out the transformer, it has to be a loose connection between it and the house, probably either in the meter base or the main panel. This is dangerous and you need to involve the POCO and and an electrician asap.

Comment: I ran into a very similar situation at the Parsonage House on my church's property.  It was a very old meter base and several fuse panels, (yes true fuses, not breakers).  The power would go off in part of the house and then come back. The POCO, pulled the meter base cover and found a burned lug on one of the hots. It would conduct for a while, get hot, expand/move, break the connection, then cool/move and reconnect. Obviously a very dangerous situation. We ended up replacing the meter base and consolidated all circuits in a new main panel.

Comment: This isn't really correct. In the US, you get 1 phase to your house typically, which is 240 volt. The 2 legs of 120V are derived by splitting that phase, this type of service is called "split-phase".

Comment: @PhilippNagel Thanks for the correction.  I assume this error was the source of the down vote; justifiably so.  While I don't see this as terribly important to the OP's question, I edited my response to be more accurate.  Please feel free to further edit (or suggest edits) if needed.  Thanks again for catching this.